# Can static data for Datagrid rows be defined purely in XAML i.e. no code behind?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have static data that I want to display in Datagrid format. The values are for display purposes only and will not change. Can it be added as some kind of subtag of the Datagrid control so I can avoid anything in the codebehind?

It has to be Datagrid control only as the purpose is to experiment with and demo certain Datagrid UI features with dummy blah blah content.

If pure XAML content is not possible then what is the best (quick & dirty) method to set up dummy content for a datagrid? Can it be done without writing classes etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the example section on this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.100).aspx)

Since the datagrid uses ItemsControl similar to Combobox or ListBox, datagrid should be the same logic. In that example they basically create a whole collection of objects in pure XAML.

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="Employees" XPath="/Employees/*">
  <x:XData>
    <Employees xmlns="">
      <Employee Name="Terry Adams" Type="FTE" EmployeeNumber="1" />
      <Employee Name="Claire O&apos;Donnell" Type="FTE" EmployeeNumber="12345" />
      <Employee Name="Palle Peterson" Type="FTE" EmployeeNumber="5678" />
      <Employee Name="Amy E. Alberts" Type="CSG" EmployeeNumber="99222" />
      <Employee Name="Stefan Hesse" Type="Vendor" EmployeeNumber="-" />
    </Employees>
  </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>

<DataTemplate x:Key="EmployeeItemTemplate">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
</DataTemplate>


...

<ListBox Name="employeeListBox"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Employees}}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeItemTemplate}"
         SelectedValue="12345"
         SelectedValuePath="@EmployeeNumber"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=employeeListBox, 
                  Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

Comment: Why down vote?People,if you are downvoting on an answer, you needto have a decensy of at least of adding a comment on "why"

Comment: No, its not link only.. If I just stopped after the first line, then it would have! I actually explained why the example in the linked article will actually be helpful to the OP. Hence its marked as "Accepted Answer". But any way.!

Comment: the example section on the page you linked seems to be empty

Comment: This is 6 year question, and MSDN links point to latest version, I have now pasted the actual example here.

Answer (score 36):

Here is pure XAML static data binded on a datagrid:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStaticDataBinding.XMLWindows"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="XMLWindows" Height="152" Width="294">
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MockList"   XPath="/MockObjects/*" >
        <x:XData >
            <MockObjects xmlns="">
                <MockObject  Name="Louis" Type="TTTT" Number="1" />
                <MockObject Name="Joseph" Type="TTTT" Number="2" />
                <MockObject Name="Papineau" Type="ZZZZ" Number="3" />
            </MockObjects>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MockList}}">
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=Default, XPath=/MockObjects/MockObject}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Type}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Number}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

I wasn't able to autogenerate columns using XmlDataProvider (I'm probably missing something):

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MockList}}">
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=Default, XPath=/MockObjects/MockObject}">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

But using a code Behind class like Dave Suggestion allow AutoBinding to work and in my opinion is much simpler (I preferred the `ResourceDictionary` approach though)  :

Code:

```
namespace WpfStaticDataBinding
{
    public class MockRecord
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStaticDataBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfStaticDataBinding"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="157" Width="302">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:Array x:Key="MyDumbMockedList" Type="local:MockRecord">
            <local:MockRecord FirstName="Fred" LastName="Flintstone" Email="fred@noemail.org" />
            <local:MockRecord FirstName="Wilma" LastName="Flintstone" Email="wilma@noemail.org" />
            <local:MockRecord FirstName="Barney" LastName="Rubble" Email="barney@noemail.org" />
        </x:Array>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid  Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyDumbMockedList}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for putting that up, Guish.  I followed your first example but I get this run time error: 'System.Windows.Data Error: 50 : XmlDataProvider has inline XML that does not explicitly set its XmlNamespace (xmlns="").'  The data do appear in the grid however.  But if I remove the namespace the data aren't inserted in the grid but I get no error message.  If I put in "x" (without the quote marks) it also doesn't work.  How do I get around this conundrum?

Comment: I did a little search and found this link.... I don't know if it can help you: [http://blog.wouldbetheologian.com/2009/07/why-wpf-databinding-is-awful-technology.html](http://blog.wouldbetheologian.com/2009/07/why-wpf-databinding-is-awful-technology.html)

Comment: The example in that link ALSO gives an Error 50.  Based on the first example in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173979/issues-with-data-binding-while-working-with-wpf) I tried to add a XmlNamespaceMappingCollection to my Window.Resources but I get the error message: The type does not implement IList: XmlNamespaceMappingCollection.  So I am again stuck.

Answer (score 19):

You can do static data in XAML, yes, but you will need to create a simple class for the record format. For example, you could create this class file:

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
    public class MockRecord
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now in your XAML DataGrid you can do this:

```
<DataGrid xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNamespace">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost" Binding="{Binding Email}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

     <!-- Static Data which will automatically go in the datagrid -->
     <local:MockRecord FirstName="Fred" LastName="Flintstone" Email="fred@noemail.org" />
     <local:MockRecord FirstName="Wilma" LastName="Flintstone" Email="wilma@noemail.org" />
     <local:MockRecord FirstName="Barney" LastName="Rubble" Email="barney@noemail.org" />
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Had almost same solution except I missed the part with xmlns:local. It worked when compiled but I couldn't see it in the XAML Designer even though xmlns:local definition was present in my UserControl's definition in which DataGrid is located. Thank you very much for sharing.