# Defining data source declaratively in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have list controls with small, static data sources. For example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" .../>
```

and my view model populates the list:

```
this.Countries.Add(new Country { Code = "BE", Name = "Belgium" });
this.Countries.Add(new Country { Code = "CA", Name = "Canada" });
// etc.
```

Is there an alternative way to define the list contents in XAML instead? Something like:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <somenamespace:list>
            <mynamespace:Country Code="BE" Name="Belgium" />
            etc.
        </somenamespace:list>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
</ItemsControl>
```

I would actually put the lists in separate resource files and would hope to do `ItemsSource="{StaticResource myListOfCountries}"` after defining them as a resource.

I want to do this to lighten the boilerplate code in my VMs. I wonder if it would negatively affect performance as those objects could be created before the view is rendered, while I could otherwise load these later (on navigated to, on view load, ... vs contructor). Any thoughts welcome!

Comment: This link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/06/limitedgenericssupportinxaml.aspx) might help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a new CollectionType, and then populating it in XAML.

Example,

**CollectionType that will be used in XAML:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public class CountryCollection : ObservableCollection<Country>
    {
    }
}
```

**POCO:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public class Country 
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CountryCollection x:Key="CountryList">
            <local:Country Name="Canada" Code="CA"/>
            <local:Country Name="United States" Code="US"/>
            <local:Country Name="Belgium" Code="BE"/>
        </local:CountryCollection>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource CountryList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Code}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note, the XAML provided is similar to:

```
    var CountryList = new ObservableCollection<Country>
    {
        new Country {Name = "Canada", Code = "CA"},
        new Country {Name = "United States", Code = "US"},
        new Country {Name = "Belgium", Code = "BE"}
    };
```

**Edit (Update using an ArrayList)**

with the Collections namespace defined in XAML, you can use

```
   xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"

<Window.Resources>
    <collections:ArrayList x:Key="CountryList">
        <local:Country Name="Canada" Code="CA"/>
        <local:Country Name="United States" Code="US"/>
        <local:Country Name="Belgium" Code="BE"/>
    </collections:ArrayList>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: You don't need a get set on public class CountryCollection?

Comment: @Blam No, CountryCollection is derived from ObservableCollection, so there's not need to create a setter/getter. Through inheritance, it will still simply have all the normal functionality of an ObservableCollection. See my edit

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. Is there a way to not have to create a new collection type? I don't even need an ObservableCollection in this case, List would do (for example). Wonder if I can re-use an existing generic type.

Comment: @mleroy Yes, you do not have to create a new type if you do not plan on using an ObservableCollection. You can simply use an ArrayList instead (I added the XAML in my update)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it pure XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MockList"
                         XPath="/MockObjects/*">
            <x:XData>
                <MockObjects xmlns="">
                    <MockObject  Code="BE"
                                 Name="Belgium" />
                    <MockObject  Code="CA"
                                 Name="Canada" />
                    <MockObject  Code="US"
                                 Name="USA! USA!" />
                </MockObjects>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MockList}}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=Default, XPath=/MockObjects/MockObject}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Code}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I used [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21731719/1144624) as a reference.

Comment: Realize though that this method breaks MVVM because your "Model" (`Country`) is provided only in your view data.  Alternatively you could write an XML file and parse it into objects during initialization of your ViewModel.